# Cannot declare ViewHolder as static inner class

Tags: android

In my application, I am using a listview and have customized the associated array adapter by extending the standard the array adapter.However,inside the extended adapter, I am unable to declare the viewholder as a static inner class. Eclipse keeps giving the error that "static types can only be declared in static or top level types". Here is the code:

```
public class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public IconicAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row,values);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
        }
        TextView label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(values[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);

        return (row);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `IconicAdapter` in `IconicAdapter.java`, or is `IconicAdapter` an inner class of something else?

Comment: IconicAdapter is a inner class of the activity class which contains the list activity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `IconicAdapter` is an inner class, you won't be able to declare an inner static class within it unless `IconicAdapter` is declared as a static class.

Comment: @user1107888: Simply move `ViewHolder` to be a static inner class of the activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare:This works and I am marking the answer as accepted, but can you please elaborate the concept.Thank you.

Comment: Move `ViewHolder` outside of `IconicAdapter`, or define it in a separate java file. The concept is easy - you can't define static inner classes inside non-static inner classes