# how to declare an interface inside non static inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm working to improve an android recycler view by following this [simple tutorial](https://jonfhancock.com/your-viewholders-are-dumb-make-em-not-dumb-82e6f73f630c). I found a java issue: if I declare an interface inside a non-static view holder inner class like below...

```java
public class DumbViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //...
    ExcellentAdventureListener listener;

    public interface ExcellentAdventureListener {
        void onMapClicked(ExcellentAdventure item);
        void onTitleClicked(ExcellentAdventure item);
    }   
    //...
}
```

java gives me the following error:

> INNER CLASS CANNOT HAVE STATIC DECLARATION.

why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: In your code, I can not see any `STATIC DECLARATION`.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956340/recyclerview-inner-classes-cannot-have-static-declaration

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology. Define the interface one level out, or indeed define the *class* at the outer level, which is what must be happening in the your citation. You can't put interfaces into inner classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting your interface in an inner class? It will work fine outside.

Simply take your interface and keep it as a variable in your adapter and check if the object passed to your adapter implements the interface methods, then cast that object to your interface.